# Validator and Sanitizer for HTML 5 attribute regex according to current HTML living standard

Tags: php, html, regex, validation, utf-8

According to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2 an HTML 5 attribute name is defined like this:

> Attribute names must consist of one or more characters other than
> controls, U+0020 SPACE, U+0022 ("), U+0027 ('), U+003E (>), U+002F
> (/), U+003D (=), and noncharacters. In the HTML syntax, attribute
> names, even those for foreign elements, may be written with any mix of
> ASCII lower and ASCII upper alphas.

Creating a class which can handle or sanitize HTML 5 attribute names I have ended up with the following code - especially the following regex:

```
class AttributeNameValidator
{
    public const ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATCHER = "/[\s\x{0000}\x{0020}\x{0022}\x{0027}\x{003E}\x{002F}\x{003D}\x{200B}-\x{200D}\x{FDD0}-\x{FDEF}\x{FEFF}[:cntrl:]]+/u";

    /**
     * Checks if a given string is a valid HTML attribute name.
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @return bool: True if the given attribute name is a valid HTML attribute name.
     */
    public static function isAttributeNameValid(string $attributeName): bool
    {
        return (bool)preg_match(self::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATCHER, $attributeName);
    }

    /**
     * Sanitizes a string to be a valid HTML5 attribute name.
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @return string
     * @throws NonSanitizeableException
     */
    public static function sanitizeAttributeName(string $attributeName): string
    {
        $sanitizedAttributeName = preg_replace(self::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_MATCHER, '', $attributeName);
        if(!$sanitizedAttributeName) {
            throw new NonSanitizeableException("Failed to sanitize attribute name");
        }
        return $sanitizedAttributeName;
    }
}
```

My manual tests seem to work well still I am not sure if the regex exactly matches the standard or if I have forgotten something. Is there still something to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `\x{0020}` (SPACE) character is already included in `\s`, you can omit that part.
- I prefer to use  `\p{Cc}` over `[:cntrl:]` for consistency and because I don't like to have nested square braces in a character class.
- I expect `isAttributeNameValid()` to be checking that the whole string contains NO blacklisted characters.  If you want to match the entire string then you will need "start of string" and "end of string" anchors and a negated character class in your pattern.  But wait, you have a regular character class and you are returning `true` if one or more blacklisted characters are in the string -- this seems precisely the opposite of what the method name suggests.  Unless I am confused, you should replace `(bool)` with `!` so that you return `false` when a match is made and `true` when there are no blacklisted characters found.
- I don't know if I agree with the wording of `Failed to sanitize attribute name`; it seems more truthful to say that the `Attribute name had no salvagable characters`.

Comment: Good answer. Do not know why I did not recognize 3), thanks.